# How can I connect google pay to my django project?

Tags: python, django

I am making a django project and I want to add a google pay system so that I can take payments and then provide them with the course.

I can't find anything on internet I even asked ChatGPT and Bard but they did'nt told properly so can't do anything.

Comment: through gpay  apis ?

Answer (score 1):

If there is no package already made for google pay you should use the Google Pay API:

https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/guides/tutorial

With this you can achieve the payments by doing requests to the google pay api.

Comment: is there and other method with which I can connect google pay to my django project maybe by using some simple js??